# jsonrpc4j null on JSON serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonrpc4j

I'm getting a *null* error from `jsonrpc4j` in the class `CleengAPI.java` below from which the method `rpc.listCustomers(publisherToken, offset, limit);` is called to serialize the following customer JSON list which is downloaded correctly by `jsonrpc4j` and displayed in the debug statement, but the JSON is not serialized effectively resulting in the null error.

**Customer list JSON**

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "email": "",
            "firstName": "xx",
            "lastName": "xx",
            "dateOfBirth": "",
            "country": "US",
            "companyName": "",
            "phoneNumber": "",
            "addressLine1": null,
            "addressLine2": null,
            "city": null,
            "state": null,
            "postalCode": null,
            "regDate": "2019-12-24 07:06:46",
            "lastLoginDate": "2019-12-24 07:06:46",
            "transactions": "",
            "payment": "",
            "termsAccepted": "no",
            "marketingOptIn": "no",
            "lastUserIp": "xx.xx.x.x"
        },
        {
            "email": "11@gmail.com",
            "firstName": "xx",
            "lastName": "xx",
            "dateOfBirth": "",
            "country": "US",
            "companyName": "",
            "phoneNumber": "",
            "addressLine1": null,
            "addressLine2": null,
            "city": null,
            "state": null,
            "postalCode": null,
            "regDate": "2019-02-12 02:10:57",
            "lastLoginDate": "2019-03-19 17:10:28",
            "transactions": "1",
            "payment": "visa",
            "termsAccepted": "no",
            "marketingOptIn": "yes",
            "lastUserIp": "xxx.xxx.xx.x"
        }
    ],
    "id": "854190206",
    "error": null,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

**Class CleengAPI**

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcHttpClient;
import com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcParam;
import com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.ProxyUtil;
import com.jahtoe.getner.domain.AccessStatus;
import com.jahtoe.getner.domain.Items;
import com.jahtoe.getner.domain.ListCustomers;
import com.jahtoe.getner.domain.ListCustomerSubscription;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class CleengApi {

    private CleengRpc rpc;
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CleengApi.class);

    private interface CleengRpc {

        Items<ListCustomers> listCustomers(
                @JsonRpcParam(value = "publisherToken") String publisherToken,
                @JsonRpcParam(value = "offset") int offset,
                @JsonRpcParam(value = "limit") int limit);

    }

    public CleengApi() throws MalformedURLException {
        makeRpc("https://api.cleeng.com/3.0/json-rpc");
    }

    private void makeRpc(String apiUrl) throws MalformedURLException {
        JsonRpcHttpClient client = new JsonRpcHttpClient(new URL(apiUrl));
        rpc = ProxyUtil.createClientProxy(getClass().getClassLoader(), CleengRpc.class, client);
    }

    public Items<ListCustomers> ListCustomer(String publisherToken, int offset, int limit) {
        return rpc.listCustomers(publisherToken, offset, limit);
    }    

}
```

**Class ListCustomers  to serialize JSON**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
public class ListCustomers implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String email;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String dateOfBirth;
    public String country;
    public String companyName;
    public String phoneNumber;
    public Object addressLine1;
    public Object addressLine2;
    public Object city;
    public Object state;
    public Object postalCode;
    public String regDate;
    public String lastLoginDate;
    public String transactions;
    public String payment;
    public String termsAccepted;
    public String marketingOptIn;
    public String lastUserIp;
}
```

**Code nippet to create CleanAPI and execute ListCustomers download and serialization**

```
CleengApi api = new 
allListCustomer = api.ListCustomer(publisherToken, 0, 50);
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.jahtoe.XX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XX</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>GregGetner</name>
    <description>ETL: Cleeng to Zapier</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.briandilley.jsonrpc4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonrpc4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>    
</project>
```

**Items Class**

```
package com.cleeng.apiv3.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Items<X> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public int totalItemCount;
    public java.util.Vector<X> items;
}
```

I'm not sure how to debug this as the message is simply the one word *null*

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
Conteh

Comment: It's been determined that the use of the Items class causes the null pointer. When changing Items to List the problem goes away. Not sure why Items does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what was happening is that the following style of JSON returned by the API requires the Items class

```
{
    "result": {
        "items": [{
            "offerId": "S321834685_US",
            "status": "active",
            "expiresAt": 15869957,
            "nextPaymentPrice": 79,
            "nextPaymentCurrency": "USD",
            "paymentGateway": "adyen",
            "paymentMethod": "visa"
        }],
        "totalItemCount": 1
    },
    "id": "299789347",
    "error": null,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

However this style require a List. I was using Items with this style which causes the null.

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "email": "",
            "firstName": "vvv",
            "lastName": "wwwww",
            "dateOfBirth": "",
            "country": "US",
            "companyName": "",
            "phoneNumber": "",
            "addressLine1": null,
            "addressLine2": null,
            "city": null,
            "state": null,
            "postalCode": null,
            "regDate": "2019-12-24 07:06:46",
            "lastLoginDate": "2019-12-24 07:06:46",
            "transactions": "",
            "payment": "",
            "termsAccepted": "no",
            "marketingOptIn": "no",
            "lastUserIp": "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        },
```